# Laravel: Issue when sending AJAX POST request when checkbox state changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

for the admin panel I'm building I can make posts appear as visible or invisible if you check or uncheck a checkbox, when the checkbox is clicked a POST request is send to the /posts-update-visibility method which updates the isVisble property of the Post model.

For some reason the isVisible is not being updated and isVisible ALWAYS returns 1 no matter what.

First the posts are retrieved from database with AJAX GET call:

```js
$.ajax({

                    async: true,
                    url: '/posts',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
    
                    success: function (data) { 
       
            $('.row[data-link=' + linked_entry + ']').remove();
     
         $.each(data.posts, function (index, item) {
     
             var posts_row = '<tr class="row" data-link="posts">';
                            posts_row += '<td>' + item.title + '</td>';
                            posts_row += '<td>' + item.body + '</td>';
                            posts_row += '<td><div style="width:110px; height:60px; background-image:url(' + item.image + '); background-size:cover;"></div></td>';
                            posts_row += '<td style="text-align:center;"><input type="checkbox" class="entry_checkbox" data-link="posts" data-id="' + item.id + '" data-isVisible="' + item.isVisible + '" name="isVisible" '+(item.isVisible ? 'checked' : '')+'></td>';
                            posts_row += '</tr>';
 
             $('.entry_table_container[data-link=' + linked_entry + ']').append(posts_row);
                        });
        
                 
                    },
   
           error: function (data){
                        var errors = data.responseJSON;
                        console.log(errors);
                    }
    
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then when checkbox state is detected I send POST request:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.entry_checkbox', function() {
        console.log('Checkbox state changed');
        
        linked_entry = $(this).attr("data-link");
        console.log(linked_entry);
        
        
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content') }
        });
        

        switch(linked_entry) {
            
            case "posts":
            
            
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('id', $(this).attr("data-id"));
                formData.append('isVisible', $('.entry_checkbox[data-link=' + linked_entry + ']').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0);
            
                $.ajax({
        
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    url: '/posts-update-visibility',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
            
                    success: function (data) { 
                        console.log(data.success);
                        console.log(data.visibility);
                    },
            
                    error: function (data){
                        var errors = data.responseJSON;
                        console.log(errors);
                    }
                });

            break;
                    
            default: 
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My controller method where I update isVisible (it doesn't actually updates anything and always returns 1, always, both $visibility and isVisible).

```js
public function updateVisibility(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->id;
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        $post->isVisible = $request->isVisible;
        $post->save();
        
        $visibility = $post->isVisible;
        
        return response()->json([
        
            'success' => 'Publicación actualizada correctamente',
            'post' => $post,
            'visibility' => $visibility,
        ]);
    }
```

This is js console feed: Checkbox state changed 
posts 
Publicación actualizada correctamente 
1

JSON Response
post    {…}
id  2
title   Titulo del segundo post
body    Descripcion del segundo post
image   img/posts/2.jpg
isVisible   1
created_at  null
updated_at  null
visibility  1

Comment: Are you receiving the correct value in `$request->isVisible;` ?

Comment: I just did a dd($request->all()) and it always returns 1 no matter what